# Load large data in bootstrap data table with multiple conditions and restrictions Oracle db in PHP

Tags: php, json, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, oracle11g

I am having more than 1,00,000 records in Oracle DB, PHP. I have used bootstrap data table here. Also I have used the json format here to display the records in data table. If I just display the records without any conditions and restrictions, it will load quickly and will take few seconds (15-25 Secs).

But in my case I need to verify each and every columns and apply lots of conditions and add some other activities like show background color, text bold like this. While display in the table view it will take more than 2 mins. How can we load this very quickly.